# Update and add ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two list existing list and new request list

```
"existingList" :[
{ "name" : "ExistingNameOne",
  "Value" : "ExistingValueOne"
},
{ "name" : "ExistingNameTwo",
  "Value" : "ExistingValueTwo"
},
{ "name" : "ExistingNameOne",
  "Value" : "ExistingValueThree"
}  
]

"requestListToAddOrUpdate":[
{ "name" : "RequestNameOne",
  "Value" : "RequestValueOne"
},
{ "name" : "RequestNameTwo",
  "Value" : "RequestValueTwo"
},
{ "name" : "RequestNameOne",
  "Value" : "RequestValueThree"
},

{ "name" : "ExistingNameOne",
  "Value" : "ExistingValueThreeUpdated"
}
]
```

i am converting json to arrayList and now i want to know how i can create brand new Arraylist with new/updated and existing list all together. For eg. As you can see in requestList i have one already existing attribute ExistingNameOne but with updated value i want to update just value and create new Arraylist combined.

Help appreciated !

Comment: Just put them all in a map.

Comment: Thanks you are right Map was what i was looking for.